# Dúvida no exercício de pedra, papel e tesoura

Tags: javascript

O exercício é o seguinte:

**Crie um game de jokenpo.**

A cada rodada, o jogador vê o menu "Escolha sua jogada: 1-Papel, 2-Pedra, 3-Tesoura". O jogo lê a opção do jogador e verifica se é válida. Se for inválida, o jogador perde a rodada e o jogo acaba. Se for válida, o computador escolhe uma 
resposta aleatória, que é mostrada ao jogador.

Se o jogador ganhar, ele pode jogar mais uma rodada e sua pontuação aumenta. O jogo acaba quando o 
jogador perde uma rodada. A pontuação total é mostrada no fim do jogo.

Segue meu código:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            var opcao=parseInt(prompt("Qual e a opcao  1 - Papel 2 - Pedra 3 - Tesoura"));
            var resposta=Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
            var opcaoe+="";
            var verificador=true;

            while(verificador==true){
                if(resposta==1){
                    opcaoe+="a resposta e papel";
                }
                else if(resposta==2){
                    opcaoe+="a resposta e pedra";
                }
                else if(resposta==3){
                    opcaoe+="a resposta e tesoura";
                }

                if(opcao===resposta){
                    alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
                    return verificador=false;
                }else if(opcao==1 && resposta==2){
                    alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
                    return verificador=true;
                }else if(opcao==2 && resposta==1){
                    alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
                    return verificador=false;
                }else if(opcao==3 && resposta==1){
                    alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
                    return verificador=true;
                }else if(opcao==3 && resposta==2){
                    alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
                    return verificador=false;
                }else if(opcao==2 && resposta==3){
                    alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
                    return verificador=true;
                }}else if(opcao==1 && resposta==3){
                    alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
                    return verificador=false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Duvida:** Código não funciona.

Comment: E qual sua dúvida?

Comment: A duvida e que o exercício não fonciona

Comment: Ok Diogo, passe mais detalhes, que erro está apresentando, ou qual era o resultado esperado e não aconteceu, etc....  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Não me aparece nada na pagina e eu penso que o problema esteja no prompt pois não me aparece a caixa do prompt mas eu ja tentei substituir o parseInt por ParseFloat e continua a não dar

Comment: O que aparece no console do navegador?

Comment: Verifique a abertura e fechamento das estruturas if  e while, e nos retornos remova o "verificador="  https://jsfiddle.net/y4mauehp/

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura do seu código está toda equivocada. Esses `returns` não existem e esse loop `while` é desnecessário e complicado de trabalhar nesse caso.

O melhor seria fazer isso com uma função, que fica bem mais fácil de trabalhar:

```
function inicia(){
    var opcao=parseInt(prompt("Qual e a opcao  1 - Papel 2 - Pedra 3 - Tesoura"));
    var resposta=Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    var opcaoe = "";
    var verificador=true;

    if(resposta==1){
        opcaoe+="a resposta e papel";
    }
    else if(resposta==2){
        opcaoe+="a resposta e pedra";
    }
    else if(resposta==3){
        opcaoe+="a resposta e tesoura";
    }

    if(opcao===resposta){
        alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
    }else if(opcao==1 && resposta==2){
        alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
        inicia();
    }else if(opcao==2 && resposta==1){
        alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
    }else if(opcao==3 && resposta==1){
        alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
        inicia();
    }else if(opcao==3 && resposta==2){
        alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
    }else if(opcao==2 && resposta==3){
        alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
        inicia();
    }else if(opcao==1 && resposta==3){
        alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
    }
}

inicia();
```

```js
function inicia(){
 var opcao=parseInt(prompt("Qual e a opcao  1 - Papel 2 - Pedra 3 - Tesoura"));
 var resposta=Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
 var opcaoe = "";
 var verificador=true;

 if(resposta==1){
  opcaoe+="a resposta e papel";
 }
 else if(resposta==2){
  opcaoe+="a resposta e pedra";
 }
 else if(resposta==3){
  opcaoe+="a resposta e tesoura";
 }

 if(opcao===resposta){
  alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
 }else if(opcao==1 && resposta==2){
  alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
  inicia();
 }else if(opcao==2 && resposta==1){
  alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
 }else if(opcao==3 && resposta==1){
  alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
  inicia();
 }else if(opcao==3 && resposta==2){
  alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
 }else if(opcao==2 && resposta==3){
  alert("a resposta e valida"+opcaoe+".");
  inicia();
 }else if(opcao==1 && resposta==3){
  alert("a resposta e invalida"+opcaoe+".");
 }
}

inicia();
```